# Faint clicking noise in trackpad in Macbook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, mouse, trackpad

I recently purchased a Macbook pro, and I have some issue with my Trackpad. I notice that if I lightly press on it, I can hear a *click* (sometimes faint, sometimes clearly audible) but no click action is performed. If I firmly press, then the click goes through as expected, but instead of one clear *click* noise, I hear a faint *click* followed by a louder *click*.

Has anyone heard of this before? Is it normal behavior? If not, how should I go about fixing the problem? The laptop is under warranty, so do I simply go to an Apple store and ask them to fix it for me? If so, how long does it take to replace a trackpad?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Apple repair folks won't actually replace the trackpad  itself, but they will adjust the tensioner underneath the trackpad. I had the same issue in my brand new Macbook Pro, and they were able to solve the issue.

Comment: Out of curiosity - did they do it on-site or you had to wait a couple of days for the repair?

Comment: @Michal M I think it's Apple's policy that 'Geniuses' do not perform any kind of hardware repair on the bar in front of customers. It all has to be signed off and taken out back - This usually incurs a wait time ranging from minutes to days mainly depending on the current workload.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I took it to the Apple Store and they looked at it and they didn't even open it up to see what is wrong. They just said I need to get a new trackpad that is $100.

Comment: Try going to another Apple store. I've heard there are inconsistencies in the helpfulness of the Genius bar. They fixed mine in about 10 minutes.